# creation of cbp file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to make cbp file for my ros package in order to run cmake file.
more specifically i want to edit my CPP file in QtSDk IDE.can anybody help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40556/creation-of-cbp-file/) by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions on how to use QtCreator with ROS packages are available [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#QtCreator). Is this what you're looking for? (Please edit your original question if this is not the case)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0